# Equalizing content between columns

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, calculated-columns

I am looking for an optimized way of displaying dynamically generated items sorted and grouped based on initials (like the image below). Groups can have different number of items and therefore also the total number of items is not known.

What would be the best solution to spread the groups across columns(they should remain sorted)?

Currently the groups and items are generated from php and spread across columns(divs) which contain the groups and items within ul and li items.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub3mg3twm0eg8b6/columns.jpg

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Here is the html structure : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lllzp5dbmwi5m08/columns.txt .. I found some solutions to split the content based on the total number of li's but that doesn't work because the li's should work as a group..

Comment: Best fit = Total number items / number columns.  Then fill each column until the half way point of the next block of items is past the end of the column, and go to the next one.

Comment: Thank you @leftclickben, this seems like the best approach so far..

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts and this will work as a polyfill https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks you just need a push to get started he's what I would do. Since your columns are dynamically generated I assume you're using PHP for that you should:

1. Count each item in the columns
2. Count all items on the whole page
3. Divide that by three
4. Next you'd output the first third until the last item of the last group
5. Count all the items in the first column
6. Next output starting at the first item of the new group and output as many items as in the first group excluding the last group
7. Output the rest of the items in de last column

Needs some tweaking of course. Good luck!

Comment: I figured this out but the problem is that the items of a group cannot be separated (they need to remain on the same column including the header of the group) so if I spread groups (across columns) based on the average number of items for a column than I won't get approximate even columns because the pixel error can be quite large in that case..

Comment: Updated my answer with more clarification

Comment: thank you for your answer but you are explaining how can I spread groups through columns but not an equalized way. This still gives a high pixel error = in a few cases the result will not be columns with similar height(content height)..

Comment: It's the best solution, if you don't want to split the groups then you'll always have this "pixel error"